# How to mock timer with Jest in React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Im unable to test my function as i have a timer in between . How can i mock timer with Jest

"await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))"

```
async callAPI(user) {
   await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
   //Code.....
   try{
   .....
    }catch (error) {

   }
}
```

Comment: Jest has fake timers: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wait for 1 second, you can do it with [jest fake timers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks):

```js
jest.useFakeTimers();

it('test something after 1sec', () => {


  // Wait for 1 sec
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);

  ...
});
```